# how to write connection string for this sql server 2008 in asp.net with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

This is my sql server connection page.. How can i write connection string for this in asp.net using c# ?

This is my connection string :

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="con" connectionString="Data Source=RANA-PC;Initial Catalog=test;User ID='';Password=''" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

This is my connection instances in `default.aspx` :

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data source = RANA-PC; database=test;  uid = ''; password =''");
```

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can read in the connection string direct from configuration and pass it to the `SqlConnection` constructor:

```
string connection_string = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connection_string);
```

Just make sure the connection string is declared in your Web.config.